# How tracnform rest of json into one field value using jolt?

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

Here is the JSON input:

```json
{
  "myRootKey": {
    "directMove": "directValue",
    "marker": "THE_MARKER",
    "someTextField": "someString",
    "someObject": {
      "someKey": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

the output should be:

```json
{
  "myRootKey": {
    "subKey": {
      "directMove": "directValue"
    },
    "THE_MARKER": {
      "someTextField": "someString",
      "someObject": {
        "someKey": "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With direct moving it is clear, but how rest of the input to the `marker` object value?

Answer (score 0):

You match down to "someTextField" and "someObject", but use the new "@" / look up the tree logic to find the "marker" to use as an ouput path.

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "myRootKey": {
        "directMove": "myRootKey.subKey.directValue",
        "someTextField": "@(1,marker).someTextField",
        "someObject": "@(1,marker).someObject"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

- `@(1,marker)` allows you to retrieve the value of the marker field
- `&1` retrieves the value of the matching node

So the spec you are looking for looks like :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "myRootKey": {
        "directMove": "myRootKey.subKey.directValue",
        "someTextField": "&1.@(1,marker).someTextField",
        "someObject": "&1.@(1,marker).someObject"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this spec fully dynamically:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "directMove": "&1.subKey.&",
        "*TextField": "&1.@(1,marker).&",
        "*Object": "&1.@(1,marker).&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```